# How to remove a file in C program?

Tags: c, file, fclose

How do I close a file and remove it?

I have the following code:

```
FILE *filePtr = fopen("fileName", "w");
...
```

Now I want to close filePtr and remove the file "fileName".

Should I:

```
fclose(filePtr);
remove("fileName");
```

Or:

```
remove("fileName");
fclose(filePtr);
```

Does it matter which I do first?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

That is OS-dependent. On *nix, deleting an open file leaves it open and the data on disk, but removes the filename from the filesystem, and actually deletes the file on close; some other operating systems may not let you delete an open file at all. Therefore the former is recommended for maximum portability.

Comment: so I should first fclose and then remove (if I aim at *nix)? thanks!

Comment: As the answer says, *nix does not care about the order of operations. It is other operating systems you must worry about.

Comment: Actually, the file will be deleted from the disk only when the link count to file reaches 0. `unlink` will only decrement link count.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to `fclose` and then [unlink](http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlink).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `fopen` a file to `remove` it. But, in linux, if you `remove` an `fopen`ed file, it will be deleted only after closing it. You can still read/write to it.

Answer (score 0):

As man unlink(2) says (for Unix systems) :

> The unlink() function removes the link
>   named by path from its directory and
>   decrements the link count of the file
>   which was referenced by the link.  If
>   that decrement reduces the link count
>   of the file to zero, and no process
>   has the file open, then all resources
>   associated with the file are
>   reclaimed.  If one or more process
>   have the file open when the last link
>   is removed, the link is removed, but
>   the removal of the file is delayed
>   until all references to it have been
>   closed.

So the order doesn't matter at all.