# How to delete a file without using remove system call in a C program?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I've been curious how `rem` in Linux works and trying to write my own `C` code that can delete a file but when I searched for the answer, I only got the programs that were using `remove()` system call.

Is there any other way of doing it without using system call like writing your own code to do the job?

I've accomplished copying file through C filing but can't find a solution to delete a file through C.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use the remove-call?

Comment: I dont think we can achieve this, as deleting a file from memory (i.e. hard disc) is as simple as our code is interacting with harwares, and for this we have to take use of kernels(i.e. System Calls).

Comment: `remove` isn't even a system call.

Comment: May be [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx) can be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a file in C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5769785/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to delete a file use the

```
remove
```

function. If you want to have a look behind the scenes of the standard library, you may download the source of the glibc (e.g.) and have a look at the implementation. You will see that actually a INTERNAL_SYSCALL will be performed on linux os:

```
result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (unlink, err, 1, file);
```

(from /sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/unlinkat.c from the debian eglibc-2.15 package)

If you want to go further and even not use that syscall you will have to implement your own file system logic since the file system syscall just gives an abstraction layer to different filesystems.

Comment: Is remove considered a system call then?

Answer (score 11):

```
int unlink (const char *filename)
```

The unlink function deletes the file name filename. The function unlink is declared in the header file unistd.h. This function returns 0 on successful completion, and -1 on error

Comment: I mentioned above i dont want to ue system calls is it possible with c filing like we do copying with it

Comment: @Datta: You can't remove anything without using a system call. The only question is how convenient the system call will be, and how direct. For example, you can use `system()` to run the `rm` command, but that uses `fork()` and `exec*()` and `waitpid()` and other system calls in the program that calls `system()`, and the `rm` program ends up using the `unlink()` system call anyway, because there's no way to do it without using a system call, whether that's via 'INTERNAL_SYSCALL' (a system call interface) or via some other mechanism. An ordinary program can't delete a file; only the kernel can.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the clean, usual way, you can open /dev/sd** and play with your file system.

Btw, remove() isn't a syscall (man 3 remove).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to delete a file is to use the [unlink(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) function, which is called from [remove(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove), if path is a file.

Comment: Or better... use the `remove()` function which does the very same thing, but is C standard. `#include <stdio.h> ... int remove(const char *filename);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(){
        int status;
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(-1 == pid){
                printf("fork() failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else if(pid == 0){
                execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "rm /tmp/san.txt", (char *) NULL);
        }else{
                printf("[%d]fork with id %d\n",pid);
                waitpid(pid,&status,0);
        }
return 0;
}
```