# shred and remove files in linux from a C program

Tags: c, linux, file, shred

I want to shred some temp files produced by my C program before the files are removed.

Currently I am using

```
system("shred /tmp/datafile");
system("rm /tmp/datafile");
```

from within my program, but I think instead of calling the `system` function is not the best way (correct me if I am wrong..) Is there any other way I can do it? How do I shred the file from within my code itself? A library, or anything? Also, about deletion part, is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16564576/1842699) good?

Comment: Check the source code of the wipe utility. Another option would be to mount /tmp to a ram drive.

Comment: shred means overwriting the disk blocks where the file contents are present with random bytes so as to make those contents unretrievable by some tools like disc recovery.

Comment: Overwrite the content of the file with zeros ?

Comment: http://wipe.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I ask why you think this is not the best way to achieve this?  It looks like a good solution to me, if it is genuinely necessary to destroy the file contents irretrievably.

The advantage of this way of doing it are:

- the program already exists (so it's faster to develop); and
- the program is already trusted.

The second is an important point.  It's possible to overstate the necessity of elaborately scrubbing files (Peter Gutmann, in a remark quoted on the relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method), has described some uses of his method as ‘voodoo’), but that doesn't matter: in any security context, using a pre-existing tool is almost always more defensible than using something home-made.

About the only criticism I'd make of your current approach, using `system(3)`, is that since it looks up the `shred` program in the `PATH`, it would be possible in principle for someone to play games with that and get up to mischief.  But that's easily dealt with: use `fork(2)` and `execve(2)` to invoke a specific binary using its full path.

That said, if this is just a low-impact bit of tidying up, then it might be still more straightforward to simply `mmap` the file and quickly write zeros into it.

Comment: I am not against using existing programs or applications.. Its just that the `system()` call in C code that's worrying me. What if the system doesn't have the shred program installed and the `system("shred xyz");` just fails?

Comment: Is there a library to do this easily instead of calling binary programs?? That would be really great!

Comment: @ShaaradDalvi The way I would deal with that is by identifying the `shred` program (or a platform-suitable alternative) at build/configuration time. That is, you use something like [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Generic-Programs.html) to identify the path to the program and store it in a `#define`, then use that as the first argument of your `execve` call.

Comment: I'm not sure that sequential writing with write() call is slower than mmap() especially on a small files.

Comment: @MaxFomichev I doubt it would make much speed difference either way. But it seems (to me) to indicate the intention more clearly, which is a possible advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4096
#define ABS_FILE_PATH "/tmp/aaa"

int main()
{
    //get file size
    struct stat stat_buf;
    if (stat(ABS_FILE_PATH, &stat_buf) == -1)
        return errno;
    off_t fsize = stat_buf.st_size;

    //get file for writing
    int fd = open(ABS_FILE_PATH, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    //fill file with 0s
    void *buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    ssize_t ret = 0;
    off_t shift = 0;
    while((ret = write(fd, buf,
                       ((fsize - shift >BUF_SIZE)?
                       BUF_SIZE:(fsize - shift)))) > 0)
        shift += ret;
    close(fd);
    free(buf);
    if (ret == -1)
        return errno;

    //remove file
    if (remove(ABS_FILE_PATH) == -1)
        return errno;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or indeed `mmap` plus `memset` plus `munmap`.