# How to force deletion of file in C?

Tags: c, linux

How can I remove opened file in linux?

In shell I can do this:

```
rm -rf /path/to/file_or_directory
```

But how can I do it in C?

I don't want to using `system()` function.

I have seen unlink and remove method but it's haven't any flags to set force deletion.

Comment: The `-f` argument to `rm` suppresses the prompt (and ignores non-existent files). The `unlink` and `remove` functions don't have prompts and handle non-existent files differently. Basically, they always 'force' deletion, extra flags aren't necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a file in C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5769785/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `unlink` and `remove` functions force deletion. The `rm` command is doing extra checks *before* it calls one of those functions. But once you answer `y`, it just uses that function to do the real work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hope this answers your question.. This program searches the current directory for the filename, you have to add the feature of opening a different directory, which shouldn't be too hard... I don't understand the last line of your question, can you elaborate? But flags aren't necessary for remove and unlink (They force delete)...

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int status;
   char file_name[25];

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to delete\n");
   fgets(file_name,25,stdin);

   status = remove(file_name);

   if( status == 0 )
      printf("%s file deleted successfully.\n",file_name);
   else
   {
      printf("Unable to delete the file\n");
      perror("Error");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use [`gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html)! Also declare `main`'s return value: `int`.

Comment: @Kninnug Thanks for pointing that out wrote it fast! Thanks again!

Comment: so close to being able to comment, 5rep pts away:D

Answer (score 1):

To perform a recursive removal, you have to write a moderately complicated program which performs a file system walk. ISO C has no library features for this; it requires platform-specific functions for scanning the directory structure recursively.

On POSIX systems you can use `opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` to walk individual directories, and use programming language recursion to handle subdirectories. The functions `ftw` and its newer variant `nwft` perform an encapsulated file system walk; you just supply a callback function to process the visited paths.  `nftw` is better because it has a `flags` argument using which you can specify the `FTW_DEPTH` flag to do the search depth first: visit the contents of a directory before reporting the directory. That, of course, is what you want for recursive deletion.

On MS Windows, there is `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` to cob together a recursive traversal.

About `-f`, that only suppresses certain checks done by the `rm` program above and beyond what the operating system requires. Without `-f`, you get prompted if you want to delete a read-only file, but actually, in a Unix-like system, only the directory write permission is relevant, not that of the file, for deletion. The `remove` library function doesn't have such a check.

By the way, `remove` is in ISO C, so it is platform-independent. On POSIX systems, it calls `rmdir` for directories and `unlink` for other objects. So `remove` is not only portable, but lets you not worry about what type of thing you're deleting. If a directory is being removed, it has to be empty though. (Not a requirement of the `remove` function itself, but of mainstream operating systems that support it).

Answer (score 0):

`remove` or `unlink` is basically equivalent to `rm -f` already--that is, it removes the specified item without prompting for further input.

If you want something equivalent to `rm -r`, you'll need to code up walking through the directory structure and deleting items individually. Boost [Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) (for one example) has code to let you do that fairly simply while keeping the code reasonably portable.